# Rails nested Attributes with Devise (Signup form)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, nested-attributes

I am using Rails 4.2 and Devise 3.5 and trying to get nested attributes working (i've gone through multiple posts and still can't seem to fix it.)

Effectively I have a leads model and a bookings model (where a lead can have multiple bookings).

**Models**

/lead.rb

```
class Lead < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bookings
  ..
```

/booking.rb

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lead
  belongs_to :agent
  ..
```

**Controller** (pretty sure this is wrong)

```
class MyDevise::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
    build_resource({})
    resource.bookings.build
    respond_with self.resource
  end

end

 before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

 protected

 def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u|
     u.permit(:email, :password, :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :birthday, [bookings_attributes: [:unit_type, :book_date, :agent_id]])
}
 end
```

**View**

```
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-6" id="left">
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, :placeholder => "First Name", class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6" id="right">
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.text_field :last_name, autofocus: true, :placeholder => "Last Name", class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.text_field :phone_number, autofocus: true, :maxlength => 10, :placeholder => "Phone Number", class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, :placeholder => "Email", class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :placeholder => "Password (8 characters minimum)", class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <%= f.label :birthday, :display => 'block', :id => 'signup' %>
        <%= f.date_select :birthday, {:start_year => 1910, order: [:month, :day, :year] }, {:class => 'btn btn-default dropdown-toggle', :display => 'block'} %>
      </div>
      <a href="">Why do we need your birthdate?</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :bookings do |booking_form| %>
    <%= booking_form.hidden_field :book_date, :value => time_helper %>
    <%= booking_form.hidden_field :unit_type, :value => session[:unit_type] %>
    <%= booking_form.hidden_field :agent_id, :value => 1 %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Complete Booking", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary"  %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <% end %>
```

**Log output**

```
Started POST "/leads" for 172.17.0.1 at 2016-02-01 20:53:54 +0000
Cannot render console from 172.17.0.1! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by MyDevise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"chXEuFe8xLBAHT6YS/QwJvmVOwWDvt47Or5Re8kzzvblmpprxegQ4HZrOB8slrx5bG8FRjlGUsH6IkPaHDzEVA==", "lead"=>{"first_name"=>"Hugh", "last_name"=>"Kolias", "phone_number"=>"4169929038", "email"=>"hughkolias@gmail.comaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaf", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "birthday(2i)"=>"2", "birthday(3i)"=>"1", "birthday(1i)"=>"2016", "booking"=>{"book_date"=>"2016-02-11T09:15:00+00:00", "unit_type"=>"Two Bedroom", "agent_id"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Complete Booking"}
Unpermitted parameter: booking
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36mLead Exists (0.7ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "leads" WHERE "leads"."email" = 'hughkolias@gmail.comaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaf' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mLead Exists (0.6ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "leads" WHERE LOWER("leads"."email") = LOWER('hughkolias@gmail.comaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaf') LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mLead Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "leads".* FROM "leads" WHERE "leads"."confirmation_token" = $1  ORDER BY "leads"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["confirmation_token", "ab4a85d7cb85aeb981ebb6f7629a4d622f17289ff5ec9d88df18530be136d5a6"]]
  [1m[35mSQL (0.4ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "leads" ("email", "encrypted_password", "first_name", "last_name", "phone_number", "birthday", "created_at", "updated_at", "confirmation_token", "confirmation_sent_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "hughkolias@gmail.comaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaf"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$mIk06TLAJFB9EG.emLkoeO5FQ2ckBiJHBIsE16FX/8dx57kcmezsu"], ["first_name", "Hugh"], ["last_name", "Kolias"], ["phone_number", "4169929038"], ["birthday", "2016-02-01"], ["created_at", "2016-02-01 20:53:54.564453"], ["updated_at", "2016-02-01 20:53:54.564453"], ["confirmation_token", "8zxs-PG8TLDByFoyFGMr"], ["confirmation_sent_at", "2016-02-01 20:53:54.567150"]]
  Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (3.0ms)
```

Not sure where i'm going wrong... the log says unpermitted_perimeter: booking (but it should be booking_attributes).

My chrome output is below:

```
utf8:✓
authenticity_token:8EGTyqcpyWUdfcuWDtv0NB6sVa+i3aT9cQy5Iu/uV1Bnzs0ZNX0dNSsLzRFpuXhri1Zr7BglKAexkKuDOuFd8g==
lead[first_name]:John
lead[last_name]:Doe
lead[phone_number]:3546545674
lead[email]:johndoe@fsdafsadgmail.comfsdfsdafdsa
lead[password]:fsdafasfdsafsadfasd
lead[birthday(2i)]:2
lead[birthday(3i)]:1
lead[birthday(1i)]:2016
lead[booking][book_date]:2016-02-10T06:00:00+00:00
lead[booking][unit_type]:One Bedroom
lead[booking][agent_id]:1
commit:Complete Booking
```

Comment: I haven't had any direct experience overriding `Devise::RegistrationsController`, so I am not sure how to solve your problem. But I would suggest creating your own `users_controller.rb` which have the actions `:new` and `:create`. We did this in our application so we have full knowledge and control over what is happening all throughout the request-response life cycle.

Comment: Thanks @Jay-ArPolidario ... adding `resource.bookings.new` to `:create` in my own `users_controller.rb` then creates the following error (`"user_id cannot be blank"`) with the output below:
 `bookings_attributes: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
    '0': !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
      book_date: '2016-02-04T06:45:00+00:00'
      unit_type: One Bedroom
      agent_id: '1' `

I suspect its something to do with the '0' added before the attributes? Thoughts? Thanks again

Comment: @Hughberto did my answer helped you? please let us know, and consider mark my answer as accepted, I would appreciate it. thanks

Comment: Hi @SsouLlesS thanks for the response. Sorry for the typo in fields_for. I've pluralized the fields_for to `:bookings` and still get the error in my comment above '("user_id cannot be blank")' where there is a [0] before the attributes hash. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ah interesting - it seems the error was in my bookings model where I was validating lead_id, presence: true. Removing this fixes the issue. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Great! however you had a mistake in your typo in fields_for and your permitted parameters, please accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah interesting - it seems the error was in my bookings model where I was validating lead_id, presence: true. Removing this fixes the issue. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The way your form is sending the parameters is for attach only 1 booking to the user instead of "many", this is the way your booking is reaching your devise:

```
"booking"=>{"book_date"=>"2016-02-11T09:15:00+00:00", "unit_type"=>"Two Bedroom", "agent_id"=>"1"}
```

this is because in your form you are using the singular symbol:

```
  #note you are using :booking instead of :bookings that's why in your params it outputs "booking" instead of "booking_attributes"
  <%= f.fields_for :booking do |booking_form| %>
    <%= booking_form.hidden_field :book_date, :value => time_helper %>
    <%= booking_form.hidden_field :unit_type, :value => session[:unit_type] %>
    <%= booking_form.hidden_field :agent_id, :value => 1 %>
  <% end %>
```

If you just want to attach 1 booking like it is, use the following:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters #,if: :devise_controller? I think that if: is unnecesary.

 protected

 def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u|
     u.permit(:email, :password, :first_name, :last_name, :phone_number, :birthday, booking: [:unit_type, :book_date, :agent_id])
}
 end
```

then if you want to permit more than one booking then just add the plural in your `<%= f.fields_for :bookings do |booking_form| %>`

and then you can use `booking_attributes: []` in the permit statement.